# How do you tell if an object file was created with gnu or some other compiler?

Tags: c++

I think this should be a simple question, but I can't find the answer.

I am having an issue with loading a ruby c++ extension that links with precompiled .a library.
I think the issue is that I complied the extension using g++ , but I think the .a library was compiled using xlC.
I am assuming that would be a problem, right?
How can I confirm this?  Is there a way to tell which compiler created each object file?
I tried looking at obj dump,  but I could not find any thing that would directly tell me if the two objects were created with different compilers or not.

Comment: *what* would be a problem?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: this is *very* not true.

Comment: If you can demangle symbols using c++filt from the gcc distro, it's likely a g++ (or perhaps clang++) compiled binary. xlC has a different mangling scheme.

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks ... I was a bit thrown off for a while. I was not getting de-mangled names with c++filt -s gnu , I needed c++filt -s gnu-v3.  So I am able to confirm that my object file is compiled with gnu but the library is compiled with i assume xlC.  So now I at least no the cause of my problem.  I am not sure what the solution is. I guess I have to compile either the object in xlc (which was a problem when i tried) or get a version of the library compiled with gnu.  Does that sound about right?  any other idea's?

Comment: You're assuming that objects compiled with g++ and xlc can't be linked together. Are you sure that's true? There might be some extra steps involved. You should do some research on that.

Comment: I found some comments to that affect.  Here is one (old) one: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.aix/KY1xOu3fbLc  if you of any info on how to do this I would be grateful

Comment: FYI .. recompiling the library I wanted to link to using g++ solved my problem.  Thankfully I had access to the source code! Again if there is another solution, please post it as I was only lucky this time to have access to the source code.

Comment: @n.m ... if you would like to post your comment as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted.